# RQT error with pyside

Tags: pyside, ros, rqt

I am trying to use rqt_graph in ROS kinetic and I am getting the following error. I am not sure what is causing it and have no idea how to fix it. 
It seems to be a problem with an undefined symbole but not sure how this would happen.

```
 rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/rqt_graph/rqt_graph", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main.main(sys.argv, standalone='rqt_graph.ros_graph.RosGraph'))
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_gui/main.py", line 59, in main
    return super(Main, self).main(argv, standalone=standalone, plugin_argument_provider=plugin_argument_provider, plugin_manager_settings_prefix=str(hash(os.environ['ROS_PACKAGE_PATH'])))
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/main.py", line 340, in main
    from python_qt_binding import QT_BINDING
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from .binding_helper import loadUi, QT_BINDING, QT_BINDING_MODULES, QT_BINDING_VERSION  # @UnusedImport
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 252, in <module>
    getattr(sys, 'SELECT_QT_BINDING_ORDER', None),
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 98, in _select_qt_binding
    raise ImportError("Could not find Qt binding (looked for: %s):\n%s" % (', '.join(["'%s'" % b for b in binding_order]), '\n'.join(error_msgs)))
ImportError: Could not find Qt binding (looked for: 'pyqt', 'pyside'):
  ImportError for 'pyqt': /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZTI13QFileSelector
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 89, in _select_qt_binding
    QT_BINDING_VERSION = binding_loader(required_modules, optional_modules)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 131, in _load_pyqt
    _named_import('PyQt5.%s' % module_name)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 111, in _named_import
    module = builtins.__import__(name)
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZTI13QFileSelector

  ImportError for 'pyside': /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5: undefined symbol: _ZN16QLoggingCategoryD1Ev
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 89, in _select_qt_binding
    QT_BINDING_VERSION = binding_loader(required_modules, optional_modules)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 163, in _load_pyside
    _named_import('PySide2.%s' % module_name)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 111, in _named_import
    module = builtins.__import__(name)
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5: undefined symbol: _ZN16QLoggingCategoryD1Ev
 code here
```

Comment: Try reinstalling ROS following the instructions carefully given in their website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From What I can See In The Log Your pyqt and main Qt5 libs are missing And It's Not ROS Based Error

I Suggest You Install Or Reinstall Those Libs and Make Sure That Python Can Find Them